# Is this a question of Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration, network-sites, superuser

I'm a bit confused on migrating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892889/pause-resume-css-animations-when-switching-tabs) to Super User.

The OP had asked about *pausing or playing CSS animations when the browser tab is changed*. OP had also attached a code with it. When, I tested the code, it runs well for me **except** for once in 16-20 trials. I suspect that this problem could be due to *browser's internal bugs* **or** *run-time errors*. And, therefore I think that this could be better handled on Super User, but I'm still not sure about it!

What do you think?

Comment: While it could be an incompatibility in the browser or similar that's one of the issues, it's still perfectly on topic for SO as it's about using JS in a browser... It wouldn't be on topic for SU as it's not about using the *browser* itself from a user point of view... it's definitely a *development* related question.

Answer (score 8):

*is there a way to reliably pause/resume CSS animations when switching tabs?* is a programming problem and as such on-topic here.

Having to work-around browser quirks is a common task for developers to solve. No one on SU is going to solve that, except offering that the Vivaldi browser does work for that scenario 100% of the time. That answer doesn't address the question at all.

The question doesn't belong on Super User. It shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: As I said that the code is perfectly doing its work, but despite of it, the code doesn't work *sometimes*. So, how else can one solve it?

Comment: @rv7 Sometimes you just have to adjust the code to work-around the browser quirks...

Comment: @JonClements do you think that I've done any adjustments? Well, I've done and the question is more related to bugs than any codes.

Comment: @rv7 and how is SU going to help if it's a bug in the browser caused by certain user written JS exactly? If it's a bug in the browser then normally you just have to work-around it in the code... if it's not a bug in the browser but a discrete bug in the code somehow, then you still need to fix the code. Either way - it's off-topic for SU and on-topic for SO.